# TLS 1.2 to become the minimum TLS protocol level for all AWS API endpoints. How this will efect Glide and picasso library

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

Currrently I am using Glide and picasso (sperate  projects), and since the TLS 1.0/1.1 will be deprecated.
My question is how it will effect the image processing library , where we are using urls to load images.

Things I checked in picasso that it uses OkHttpClient which further uses OkhttpClient with DEFAULT protocols as

`public class OkHttpClient implements Cloneable, Call.Factory, WebSocket.Factory { static final List<Protocol> DEFAULT_PROTOCOLS = Util.immutableList( Protocol.HTTP_2, Protocol.HTTP_1_1);`

Picasso library `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8"`

Okhttp `okhttp-3.12.10`

Now I am stuck is to how the decision is being made on what protocol to use.
Any suggestions are would be grateful.

Comment: What versions of your libraries are you using? Related: https://square.github.io/okhttp/security/tls_configuration_history/

Comment: @MorrisonChang Updated the version of the library above.